# FBSDKLoginButton title localization (iOS project)

Tags: xcode7, facebook-ios-sdk

I'd like to localize title string of FBSDKLoginButton in my project, which includes FBSDKLoginKit.framework. There's a `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` in facebook-ios-sdk, as mentioned in Facebook iOS SDK FAQ about localize.

Also from source code of [FBSDKLoginButton](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/3f844053f6ee50be2d40eb75effac13e1439f9ec/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.m#L191) and [FBSDKInternalUtility](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/3f844053f6ee50be2d40eb75effac13e1439f9ec/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKInternalUtility.m#L95), I supposed it should just work by putting that bundle in my project?

But dragging `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` into my project doesn't work. Other solutions?

(It's a Swift project, but I've tried with Objective-C, same issue. Facebook SDK for iOS v4.5, 4.7 tried, with Xcode 7.0.1.)

Comment: This will add a bit of clarification: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#faq_1032895960119272

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just forgot to add my local language to project settings - Info - Localizations. My bad. And dragging [FacebookSDKStrings.bundle](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle) into project will just work.

Comment: Make sure you're using the last version of the SDK. I was having a problem with the Localization for "Continue with Facebook" button. This was fixed on 4.24.0 as you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4x#4_24_0

Answer (score 1):

I've just been confronted to this problem. Facebook documentation is a bit obscure about localization, above all when using Cocoapods.

By reading the Facebook SDK source code, I found the solution to correctly include Facebook strings files.

1. Create the `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` (which is just a folder renamed)
2. Create your langage folders in it (ex: `en.lproj` & `fr.lproj`)
3. Create a string file with the name `FacebookSDK.strings` in each language folder
4. Add the bundle to your project.

Then add each line you want to localize in each `.strings` file.

I imagine Facebook gives somewhere the exhaustive list of all keys. But if you're using Cocoapods, you can `Cmd-Shift-F` the string you want to translate (ex: `"Log in with Facebook"`) to find, in Facebook SDK source, something like

```
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"LoginButton.LogInLong", @"FacebookSDK", [FBSDKInternalUtility bundleForStrings],
                                           @"Log in with Facebook",
                                           @"The long label for the FBSDKLoginButton when the user is currently logged out");
```

which shows you the corresponding key: `LoginButton.LogInLong`

PS: [here's the `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` sample I just created.](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01527835798385203032) (unzip it before, of course)

Comment: There's [FacebookSDKStrings.bundle in facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle) with the exhaustive list of all keys. Adding that to your project would work. I've anwered my own problem. Anyway, thanks for sharing!